# Laravel Socialite Google login only with one domain

Tags: laravel, google-authentication, laravel-socialite

I have a Google+ login on my app with Laravel Socialite. When the login is done I have a callback to connect the user (I create her in database if necessary).

But I want to restrain the connection to only the company (email like "example@company.com", so only the email with "company.com").

Can I do it with Laravel Socialite ? I can make the verification manually in my callback but if Socialite can do it, it's better.

Thank you

My callback :

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider){
  $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

  if ($user) {
    $local_user = User::whereEmail($user->getEmail())->first();
    // If we don't have a user create a new user
    if (!$local_user) {
      $fragment = explode(' ', $user->getName());
      $local_user = User::create([
        'first_name' => isset($fragment[0]) ? $fragment[0] : '',
        'last_name' => isset($fragment[1]) ? $fragment[1] : '',
        'email' => $user->getEmail(),
        'last_seen' => Carbon::now(),
        'password' => ''
      ]);
      $local_user->roles()->attach(Role::whereName('User')->first());
    }
    auth()->login($local_user);
  }
  return redirect($this->redirectTo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Laravel Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/socialite) provides an abstraction for [Google OIDC](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect).

In Google OIDC you can request for specific domain with [hd parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#hd-param).

With Laravel Socialite you can pass additional parameters like this:

```php
public function redirect() {
    return Socialite::driver('google')->with([ 'hd' => "company.com" ])->redirect();
}
```

**Note that you should still verify users domain in the callback.** From [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#hd-param):

> Don't rely on this UI optimization to control who can access your app,
> as client-side requests can be modified. Be sure to validate that the
> returned ID token has an hd claim value that matches what you expect
> (e.g. mycolledge.edu)

To do this:

```php
public function callback() {
    $externalUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    if ($externalUser->user['hd'] === 'company.com') {
        // Success
    }
}
```

Here's how the consent screen will look for the user. It will only show accounts with requested domain:

[image: Google login with specific domain]

*Tested with Laravel 9, laravel/socialite v5.6.1*

Answer (score 0):

You have a [step by step guide for domain restriction](https://medium.com/employbl/add-login-with-google-to-your-laravel-app-d2205f01b895).

In controller you need to specifiy these actions:

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
    // only allow people with @company.com to login
    if(explode("@", $user->email)[1] !== 'company.com'){
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
    // check if they're an existing user
    $existingUser = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();
    if($existingUser){
        // log them in
        auth()->login($existingUser, true);
    } else {
        // create a new user
        $newUser                  = new User;
        $newUser->name            = $user->name;
        $newUser->email           = $user->email;
        $newUser->google_id       = $user->id;
        $newUser->avatar          = $user->avatar;
        $newUser->avatar_original = $user->avatar_original;
        $newUser->save();
        auth()->login($newUser, true);
    }
    return redirect()->to('/home');
}
```

Comment: The link above is broken, here is the correct link:
https://medium.com/employbl/add-login-with-google-to-your-laravel-app-d2205f01b895

Answer (score -1):

No, you can’t do it in Socialite itself because Socialite is just a mechanism of retrieving tokens from OAuth-compliant servers.

If you only want to accept users with a particular email suffix, then that’s business logic so something you should handle in your callback:

```php
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

    if (Str::endsWith($user->getEmail(), '@example.com')) {
        // Look up user and authenticate them
    }

    abort(400, 'User does not belong to organization');
}
```